# Convert single json object to json array

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to take take this object:

```json
"company_description": {
        "source": "abxf",
        "priority": "1",
        "company_description": "qpr9i",
        "product_line_description": "afij"
    }
```

and convert it into an array in postgresql. Ideally the final result would look like this:

```json
"company_description": [
        {
        "source": "abxf",
        "priority": "1",
        "company_description": "qpr9i",
        "product_line_description": "afij"
        }
]
```

I feel like there is a simple solution to this that I am missing. Any suggestions would help please!

Comment: Are you trying to convert this object to a Postgresql Array or to JSON in Postgresql?

Comment: The snippet you posted is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can just turn the value into an array using `jsonb_build_array()` and build a new JSON value from there:

```
select jsonb_build_object('company_description', 
                           jsonb_build_array(the_column -> 'company_description'))
from the_table;
```